Is there a way to detect character encoding of a blob or a string using Google Apps Script?
Looking to do this server-side (Google Apps Script) rather than to do it client-side (JS).

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, the following sample script is useful?
Sample script:
In this sample script, a javascript library encoding.js is used.
function myFunction() {
  const sampleText = "いろはにほへと"; // Sample text.

  // Load encoding.min.js
  const cdnUrl = "https://unpkg.com/encoding-japanese@2.2.0/encoding.min.js";
  eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch(cdnUrl).getContentText());

  // Create a sample data with Shift_JIS as a blob.
  // Here, I think that you can use your blob.
  const blob = Utilities.newBlob("").setDataFromString(sampleText, "Shift_JIS");

  // Convert blob to uint8Array.
  const uint8Array = [...Uint8Array.from(blob.getBytes())];

  // Detect the encoding.
  const res = Encoding.detect(uint8Array);

  console.log(res); // SJIS
}

When this script is run, SJIS is shown in the log.
An important point is required to convert int8Array to uint8Array for using it with encoding.js.
Note:

Here, the javascript library encoding.js is loaded in the script. But, if you want to directly copy and paste the library, please copy and paste it to the script editor. By this, you can use it. At that time, please remove eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText());.

Reference:

encoding.js

